# Ubuntu 10.04 - apache not serving flash files

Tags: flash, apache, ubuntu-10.04

Recently an ubuntu 10.04 server of ours stopped serving flash files.
It used to work until some days ago, then lately it was reported that there were some problems, and after investigation it's apache that's not serving .swf files for no (apparent) reason to me.

What I see in the log:

```
IP.NU.MB.ER - - [07/Nov/2012:06:05:13 +0100] "GET /path/to/ZeroClipboard.swf HTTP/1.1" 200 1385 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"
IP.NU.MB.ER - - [07/Nov/2012:06:05:19 +0100] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
```

Other files are server as usual (in fact websites are working, except for flash).

It seems to recognize the file mime_type, in fact even changing the file extension nothing happened. I've played a bit with mime-type /etc/apache2/magic file, but I can find there references to flash:

```
 # flash:        file(1) magic for Macromedia Flash file format
 #
 0       string          FWS             
 >3      byte            x                       application/x-shockwave-flash
```

also, later on the same file I find:

```
# From: Denis Knauf, via gentoo.
0       string  fLaC            audio/x-flac
0       string  CWS             application/x-shockwave-flash
```

I've read that mod_deflate could create problems with some file types, but it seemed to be configured properly, I've excluded swf files from the list of files to deflate and even disabled the module at all, still no luck.

this is the list of apache modules:

```
$'ls' /etc/apache2/mods-enabled                                                                             
alias.conf            autoindex.conf  fastcgi.conf      proxy.conf
alias.load            autoindex.load  fastcgi.load      proxy_http.load
auth_basic.load       cgi.load        mime.conf         proxy.load
authn_file.load       deflate.conf    mime.load         reqtimeout.conf
authz_default.load    deflate.load    negotiation.conf  reqtimeout.load
authz_groupfile.load  dir.conf        negotiation.load  rewrite.load
authz_host.load       dir.load        php5.conf         setenvif.conf
authz_user.load       env.load        php5.load         setenvif.load
```

also, 
when I try to access the server via wget, it simply timeout after a while

```
 $ wget http://server/test/ZeroClipboard.swf.jpg
 --2012-11-07 09:29:11--  http://server/test/ZeroClipboard.swf.jpg
 Risoluzione di server  (server)... IP.NU.MB.ER
 Connessione a server (server)|IP.NU.MB.ER|:80... connesso.
 Richiesta HTTP inviata, in attesa di risposta... Errore di lettura nelle intestazioni (Connessione scaduta).
 Altro tentativo in corso.

 --2012-11-07 09:44:12--  (tentativo: 2)  http://server/test/ZeroClipboard.swf.jpg
 Connessione a server (www.ctl.sns.it)|IP.NU.MB.ER|:80... connesso.
 Richiesta HTTP inviata, in attesa di risposta...
```

it's italian:

Errore di lettura nelle intestazioni (Connessione scaduta) is:
 Read error (%s) in headers.
 where (%s) is "Connection timed out"

Hope these info are enough...

Comment: Nothing wrong with a 200

Comment: yes, sorry, maybe it wasn't stated very clear: the flash files never reach the browser. If I access it with chrome, I can see in the "Network" tab of its developer tools that it's "Pending". It keeps being pending for 15 minutes or so, and then it stop trying.

Comment: Does the file download ok if you try to get it directly with curl or wget?

Comment: @Ben: sorry I should have written that: no, even wget can't download the file

Comment: @danilo: what error message or behaviour do you see from wget?

Comment: @wvxvw: I thought I've already added this comment, anyway: commenting out FWS and/or CWS (see updated message, I've found reference to CWS too) didn't work

Comment: @danilo: can you edit your question to include that output? it's hard to read in a comment.

Comment: question updated with wget output, please note it takes some minutes to timeout

Comment: after further investigation, the problem seems to live outside the server... let's wait for network admins to reply...

Thanks to anyone who replied, you helped me a lot!